# Matlab: conditional partition of sorted vector into parts

Tags: matlab, vector

Is there any smart way of diving sorted vector into two parts condtion on value?

```
A = [5 4 4 4 3 3 2 1];
```

I want two vectors, one that has all numbers greater than 3 and the other vector that contains the remaining number. Is arrayfun the only solution for this problem?

Comment: current solution : [1,col]=find(A(:,:)>=value,1,'last');
B=A(1,col:end);  Can I do any better than that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B = A(A >= val);
C = A(A < val);
```

Comment: eh... sometimes simplicity is all we're looking for